# The right way to wait for input after sigaction handling ctrl+c aka SIGINT

Tags: c++, c++11, sigaction

This program will print infinite "Enter a:" to the command line, after sending SIGINT via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>. To exit this loop, I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd>. If I uncomment the line containing `std::cin.clear();`, everything works fine. My question is, is this the right way to do it? One would have to set `std::cin.clear();` in front of every cin/cout he wants the program to wait for. That's why it seems not to be the proper way to me.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<signal.h>

void sig_handler(int s)
{
  std::cout << "Cought: " << s << std::endl;
  // do something...
}


int main ()
{
  struct sigaction sigIntHandler;
  sigIntHandler.sa_handler = sig_handler;
  sigemptyset(&sigIntHandler.sa_mask);
  sigIntHandler.sa_flags = 0;
  sigaction(SIGINT, &sigIntHandler, NULL);
  int a=1;
  while(a)
    {
      std::cout << "Enter a:" << std::endl;
      //std::cin.clear(); // Uncomment me!
      std::cin >> a;
    }
}
```

PS: I know that cout in signal handlers are a bad idea.

PPS: Everything works fine (without `std::cin.clear();`) when I use the old (deprecated) `signal()`.

PPPS: Just to make it clear, I do not want to exit the program on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>!

Comment: I haven't tried this but can't you put that cin clear line in the signal handler?

Comment: No, I tried this, but unfortunately it does not work.